# D3 and Leaflet: Click to zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I've used D3 to place some data onto a Leaflet map. Now, I am trying to enable the "click to zoom" function.

There's an example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590) by Mike Bostock which does it only on D3
There's an example [here](http://techslides.com/demos/leaflet/leaflet-country-zoom.html) which does it only on Leaflet.

How should I go about combining these functions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216347/achieving-animated-zoom-with-d3-and-leaflet